# Finding the maximum curvature

Tags: calculus, curvature, applications

I am trying to find the maximum curvature of $y=1/x$. I know to begin, I find k(x), which is: $k(x) = \frac {2}{x^3 (1+1/x^2)^{3/2}}$. But I'm confused as to where to go from here.

Comment: Do you know how to find the maximum value of a function?

Comment: Double check your curvature formula.  I got $$k(x) = \dfrac{2}{(x^3 + 1/x^4)^{3/2}} = 2(x^2+x^{-2})^{-3/2}$$  Note also that the curve is symmetric across the line $y=x$, so you would expect $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ to be critical points of the curvature.

Comment: I get $k = \frac{2 x^3}{(1+x^4)^{3/2}} $ which might be easier to get a derivative of.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum (or minimum) of *any* function should happen when $f'(x)=0$.

In this case $f(x) = k(x)$, so set the derivative of the curvature to zero $k'(x)=0$ and solve for $x$. The use this $x$ to get the value of the curvature.